# Recursion stack - Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying this recursion thing in Javascript, and found the numbers are printed out in the wrong order (Desc, whereas I was expecting Asc). Why is this, and how can I visualise the process?

```
(function hi(x) {
    if (x > 1000) {
        return;
    } else {
        x+=1;
        setTimeout(hi(x), 100000);
        console.log(x);
    }
})(4)
```

Comment: Try adding another `console.log(x)` statement before the `setTimeout` call to help you visualise what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You though the first argument passed to `setTimeout` is a function, but it's not.

When you do:

```
setTimeout(hi(x), 100000);
```

it means:

1. evaluate the expression `hi(x)` to get its value
2. after 100000ms, if the value from previous step is

   - callable, call it (with arguments if passed)
   - otherwise evaluate it (similar to `eval`)

so it equals:

```
var ret = hi(x);
setTimeout(ret, 100000);
```

Apparently `ret` is not your function `hi`, but the return value of it - `undefined`. So `setTimout(undefined, 100000)` actually does nothing meaningful - `eval(undefined)` after 100000ms.

Strip that out, your code equals:

```
(function hi(x) {
    if (x > 1000) {
        return;
    } else {
        x+=1;
        hi(x);
        console.log(x);
    }
})(4)
```

What's this? Yes, **synchronous** recursive function call. That's why you see the result in console is counting down rather you expected.

The solutions, besides wrapping it in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    hi(x);
}, 100000);
```

Alternatively you can also pass extra arguments to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(hi, 100000, x);
```

Arguments passed to `setTimout` after the delay, will be passed in `hi` when invoking it.

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to :

```
(function hi(x) {
    if (x > 1000) {
        return;
    } else {
        x+=1;
        setTimeout(function (){hi(x);}, 100);
        console.log(x);
    }
})(4)
```

change is in here:

```
function (){hi(x);}
```

This :

```
 setTimeout(hi(x),
```

Invokes the function immediately. you don't want that.

You want a *function* that will run `hi(x)` after 100000 ms.